# How to insert < and > in when using hyperref package?

Tags: hyperref

My code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\renewcommand*{\LayoutCheckField}[2]{#2 #1}
We want to build up a statistical model to predict tution fees of students. We will use these information to build up the model. Your privacy must be ensured. Please help us for developing the model by giving your information mentioning below-\\\\

\TextField[name=name,align=0]{Name:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=year]{Year:}{1st,2nd,3rd,4th,MS}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=university]{University:}{DU,BUET,DMC,JU,JNU}\\\\
  \TextField[name=dept.]{Department:}  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=section]{Section:}{Science,Arts,Commerce}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=hsscsection]{HSC Section:}{Science,Arts,Commerce}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hsscCollege]{HSC College:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hall]{Hall:}\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=hall]{}{mess,Basha}\\\\
  \TextField[name=homedistict]{Home District:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=foccupation]{Father's occupation:}{Farmer,Job holder,Businessman}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=moccupation]{Mother's occupation:}{Housewife,Job holder}\\\\
  \TextField[name=familymembers]{Family members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=earningmembers]{No. of earning members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=birthposition]{Birth Position:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=texperi]{Experienc as tutor:}{no,1y,2y,3y,4y,4up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=scholarship]{Getting scholarship per month:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=takingmoneyhome]{Getting money per month from home:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \TextField[name=tourcount]{Number of tour per year:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=meal]{From where taking meal:}{Hall dyning/mess, Hall canteen, hotel,Basha}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=GF]{Having GF?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=smoker]{Smoker?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=readd]{Having readdmission?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=result]{Result:}{\textless 2.5,<3.00,<3.5,<4.00}\\\\

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

This code results:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 6--7


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 6--7

(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omlcmr.fd)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\font@name ->
             \OML/cmr/m/n/10 
l.29 ...]{Result:}{\textless 2.5,<3.00,<3.5,<4.00}
                                                  \\\\
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on questionaire.log.
```

The errors are occurred for using `\textless`. Now, how can I insert `<` and `>`?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` should help

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I don't like to use `T1` because of **The default Computer Modern font does not support T1** see LaTeX wikibook chapter 9.5

Comment: Use another encoding then...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can't I use `\textless` and similar command?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I like the default font.

Comment: Use `$<2.5$,$<3.00$,$<3.5$,$<4.00$` instead.

Comment: There is no reason not to use [T1] encoding. You still will get the same look. Try it out. (It is neverless interesting to find out, why \textless loops)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As default hyperref use the values not only as label for the fields, but also as export value for the form. This can be problematic if the values contains complicated commands meant for typesetting. In such cases you can set explicit (simpler) export values with a keyval syntax: The difference between the displayed text an the value can be seen if you add a button to show the value of the field (which also the one who would be exported or sent to a script):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{Form}

\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=result,default=A]{Result:}{\textless 2.5=A,\textless 3.5=B,\textless 4.5=C}

\medskip     
\PushButton[onclick={app.alert("The value is " + this.getField("result").value)}]{Submit}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is your solution better than Nicola Talbot [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394323/how-to-insert-and-in-when-using-hyperref-package/394376#comment980356_394323)?

Comment: It is more generic.

Comment: if you described more your answer, then it might be helpful for beginners including me.

Comment: I added an edit.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal You can combine both my comment and Ulrike's answer with `$<2.5$=A,$<3.00$=B,$<3.5$=C,$<4.00$=D` (numeric relationships look better in math mode, but the assignment of a  *text* = *label* approach is the important point).

Comment: Could you cite a reference where this *text* = *label* syntax is documented?

Comment: @GuM The [official `hyperref` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf) is very sketchy as far as PDF forms are concerned, but @NicolaTalbot's freely accessible book contains a [nice overview](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/admin/html/eforms.shtml).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer would you give me a documentation link that describe the `app` functionalities and features?

Comment: @GuM as diabonas wrote the documentation is rather sketchy. I found the key-val-syntax by looking in the code - I was quite sure that Heiko had thought about the difference between exported value and visual label. He is quite good in such details.

Comment: @alhelal: `app.alert` is javascript. So find a javascript tutorial. You can also look in the eforms-manual (eformman.pdf, in the acrotex bundle), it has a number of examples about javascript in pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can I make `csv` file using the `app` functionality? [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394455/how-to-get-csv-file-from-a-filled-pdf-that-made-using-latex)