# How to take multiple instance's value in one fillable form using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref

I want to take number of `n` student's `name`,`roll`,`phone` values in `TextField` as follows -

[image]

I will include this in my another existing form at tail. My existing file -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\renewcommand*{\LayoutCheckField}[2]{#2 #1}
We want to build up a statistical model to predict tution fees of students. We will use these information to build up the model. Your privacy must be ensured. Please help us for developing the model by giving your information mentioning below-\\\\

\TextField[name=name,align=0]{Name:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,radiosymbol=,name=year]{Year:}{1st,2nd,3rd,4th,MS}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=university]{University:}{DU,BUET,DMC,JU,JNU}\\\\
  \TextField[name=dept.]{Department:}  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=section]{Section:}{Science,Arts,Commerce}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=hsscsection]{HSC Section:}{Science,Arts,Commerce}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hsscCollege]{HSC College:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=hall]{Hall:}\ChoiceMenu[radio,name=hall]{}{mess,Basha}\\\\
  \TextField[name=homedistict]{Home District:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=foccupation]{Father's occupation:}{Farmer,Job holder,Businessman}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=moccupation]{Mother's occupation:}{Housewife,Job holder}\\\\
  \TextField[name=familymembers]{Family members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=earningmembers]{No. of earning members:}\\\\
  \TextField[name=birthposition]{Birth Position:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=texperi]{Experienc as tutor:}{no,1y,2y,3y,4y,4up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=scholarship]{Getting scholarship per month:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=takingmoneyhome]{Getting money per month from home:}{0.00,1-2,2.1-3.0,3.1-4.0,4.1-5.0,5up}\\\\
  \TextField[name=tourcount]{Number of tour per year:}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=meal]{From where taking meal:}{Hall dyning/mess, Hall canteen, hotel,Basha}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=GF]{Having GF?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=smoker]{Smoker?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=readd]{Having readdmission?}{yes,no}\\\\
  \ChoiceMenu[radio,name=result]{Result:}{\textless 2.5=A,\textless 3.00=B,\textless 3.5=C,\textless 4.00=D}\\\\

\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

How will I make the form using `hyperref`?
P.S. You can give answer for `n > 2` and keep in mind that I have to extract the data as `csv` or other format after filling the fields.

Comment: The qu3estion is unclear.  If you just want to create a form as shown in the image, you could use a tabular or a bunch of `\makebox`es.  Keep in mind that the forms tend to overlay anything nearby.  If you want to record the results, that cannot be done with LaTeX.  The data isn't entered until LaTeX is done and the PDF is viewed.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yes, I know **The data isn't entered until LaTeX is done and the PDF is viewed.** I record the result by using `pdfminer` or using [script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394323/how-to-insert-and-in-when-using-hyperref-package?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: So the question is how to create a form like the image, and the MWE has nothing to do with it.